# Listando objetos existentes y resultados de busqueda en Django

Tags: django, django-templates

Tengo el modelo `LodgingOffer` con su respectivo Manager. Sobre el quiero efectuar algunas bùsquedas, para lo cual estoy usando `solr` y `haystack`

`LodgingOfferManager` tiene la funciòn active() para recuperar los objetos activos de `LodgingOffer` los cuales son activos si tiene el campo `is_taked = True`

```
class LodgingOfferManager(models.Manager):
    def active(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(LodgingOfferManager, self).filter(is_taked=False).filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())
```

Este es el modelo `LodgingOffer`

```
def get_images_search_path(instance, filename):
return '/'.join(['lodging_offer_images', instance.slug, filename])

class LodgingOffer(models.Model):

    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
           on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    ad_title = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False,                                                                                                max_length=255, verbose_name='Título de la oferta')

    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_images_search_path,
        blank=False, verbose_name='Fotografía',
        null=False)

    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    is_taked = models.BooleanField(_('Oferta tomada'),
        default=False,)

    objects = LodgingOfferManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.ad_title
```

Para efectuar las bùsquedas tengo este formulario:

```
class LodgingOfferSearchForm(forms.Form):
    query = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.TextInput())
```

Y la vista `LodgingOfferSearch`

```
class LodgingOfferSearch(FormView):
    template_name = 'hosts/lodgingoffer_search.html'

    form_class = LodgingOfferSearchForm()

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = LodgingOfferSearchForm(self.request.GET or None)
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

    # We get the active object records
    # I think that this is not necessary ... ?
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = LodgingOffer.objects.active()
        return qs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LodgingOfferSearch, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = self.request.user
        form = LodgingOfferSearchForm(self.request.GET or None)
        qs = LodgingOffer.objects.active()

        # We pass the results set active offer_list to template via context
        context['offer_list'] = qs

        # We ask if the form is valid, when perform a search
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data

            # We get the results with from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet() 
            # detailing query from form.
            results = SearchQuerySet().models(LodgingOffer)\
                          .filter(content=cd['query']).load_all()

            # Send some context variables to template
            total_results = results.count()
            context.update({
                'cd': cd,
                'results':results,
                'total_results': total_results,

            })
        if user.is_authenticated():
            context['userprofile'] = user.profile
        return context
```

Entonces, mi inquietud aquì, es que en mi template `lodgingoffer_search.html` yo quiero mostrar los registros ya existentes de `LodgingOffer` cuando se renderiza el template y los registros resultantes de la bùsqueda cuando efectùo alguna como tal.
Acorde a esta intenciòn, tengo:

```
<!-- We render the form input to perform the search --> 
 <form action="." method="get">
     <input type="submit" value="Buscar" class="submit-button">
     <div class="formgroup">
      <span></span>
        {{ form.query }}
    </div> <br />
 </form>

<!-- We iterate through offer_list active records existing objects -->
    {% for offers in offer_list %}
   <article class="host full-width" >
       <a href="{% url 'host:detail' offers.slug %}">
           <div class="img-title-cont">
               {% if offers.photo %}
                    <div class="img" style="background: url('{{ offers.photo.url }}') no-repeat center; background-size:cover;"></div>
                {% endif %}
                <div class="title-cont">
                    <h3>{{ offers.ad_title }}</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
       </a>
   </article>
{% endfor %}


<!-- We ask if the query is present in the request.GET to perform search -->

{% if "query" in request.GET %}<br />
        <p><h3>Ofertas de alojamiento que contengan: "{{ cd.query }}"</h3></p>
        <span>Encontrados cerca de {{ total_results }} resultado{{ total_results|pluralize }}</span>
    <br /><br />

    <!-- We iterate in results set from search performed --> 
    {% for result in results %}
        {% with lodgingoffer=result.object %}
        <article class="host full-width" >
            <a href="{% url 'host:detail' lodgingoffer.slug %}">
                <div class="img-title-cont">
                    {% if lodgingoffer.photo %}
                    <div class="img" style="background: url('{{ lodgingoffer.photo.url }}') no-repeat center; background-size:cover;"></div>
                    {% endif %}
                    <div class="title-cont">
                        <h3>{{ lodgingoffer.ad_title }}</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
              <hr/>
        {% endwith %}
        {% empty %}
        <p>No existen resultados para tu búsqueda de "{{ cd.query }}".</p>
    {% endfor %}
</article>
{% endif %}
```

El inconveniente que presento es que cuando entro al formulario que renderiza el template `lodgingoffer_search.html` yo veo los registros existentes de `LodgingOffer` y esto esta bien, es lo que quiero.

Pero cuando efectùo alguna bùsqueda en el formulario, yo obtengo, tanto los registros existentes de `LodgingOffer`, pero tambièn los resultados que coincidan con mi bùsqueda.

Entonces, si mi un resultado coincide con algun registro existente que muestro primero, entonces tendrè una duplicidad de registros a mostrar, lo mostraria dos veces.

En [este enlace](http://www.hostayni.com/host/lodging-offer/search/?x=0&y=0&query=cuarto) es posible ver el comportamiento

Como puedo mostrar los registros existentes cuando entro al template que renderiza el formulario, pero cuando efectue alguna busqueda que solo aparezcan los resultados que coincidan con dicha bùsqueda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿Por qúe no usas simplemente un `else`?:

```
<!-- We render the form input to perform the search --> 
 <form action="." method="get">
     <input type="submit" value="Buscar" class="submit-button">
     <div class="formgroup">
      <span></span>
        {{ form.query }}
    </div> <br />
 </form>


<!-- We ask if the query is present in the request.GET to perform search -->
{% if "query" in request.GET %}<br />
        <p><h3>Ofertas de alojamiento que contengan: "{{ cd.query }}"</h3></p>
        <span>Encontrados cerca de {{ total_results }} resultado{{ total_results|pluralize }}</span>
    <br /><br />

    <!-- We iterate in results set from search performed --> 
    {% for result in results %}
        {% with lodgingoffer=result.object %}
        <article class="host full-width" >
            <a href="{% url 'host:detail' lodgingoffer.slug %}">
                <div class="img-title-cont">
                    {% if lodgingoffer.photo %}
                    <div class="img" style="background: url('{{ lodgingoffer.photo.url }}') no-repeat center; background-size:cover;"></div>
                    {% endif %}
                    <div class="title-cont">
                        <h3>{{ lodgingoffer.ad_title }}</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
              <hr/>
        </article>
        {% endwith %}
    {% empty %}
        <p>No existen resultados para tu búsqueda de "{{ cd.query }}".</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <!-- We iterate through offer_list active records existing objects -->
    {% for offers in offer_list %}
       <article class="host full-width" >
           <a href="{% url 'host:detail' offers.slug %}">
               <div class="img-title-cont">
                    {% if offers.photo %}
                        <div class="img" style="background: url('{{ offers.photo.url }}') no-repeat center; background-size:cover;"></div>
                    {% endif %}
                    <div class="title-cont">
                        <h3>{{ offers.ad_title }}</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </a>
       </article>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

De esta forma si hay una búsqueda se muestran los resultados filtrados, de lo contrario se muestran los resultados que obtienes con `active()`.